# Two array list, passing values and using database

Tags: android

I have written code to get all the list of installed apps in the device and pick one to run. Now but I want that when an item is clicked the item should get added to another list which would be used in another activity. 
I have ActivityA which lists all the installed apps. When an user clicks an app in ActivityA it should be added to arraylist which is used in ActivityB. i.e. ActivityB will just have the apps that are selected by user in ActivityA. How can I do that?
Also this ActivityB is in another app so what should I use to store the arraylist? SQLiteDatabase or is there something much simpler than that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you essentially want to store information across applications.  The best way to do this would be through a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)